# MongoDb Driver autogenerate _id for BsonDocument

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I'm trying to create several documents within a transaction, and one of the documents needs to be inserted as a `BsonDocument` as I have to be able to mutate a couple of values prior to insertion.

The two documents that I don't need to map `.ToBsonDocument()` are properly getting a new ID generated, but the main document is not.

Here is a basic class structure that I'm using.

```cs
public abstract class BaseDto
{
    [JsonProperty("_id")] public string Id { get; init; }
    [JsonProperty("_partitionKey")] public string PartitionKey { get; init; } = Constants.MasterDataPartitionKey;
}

public class ProductDto :BaseDto
{
    public string Name { get; init; }
    public string BrandId { get; init; }
    public BrandDto Brand { get; init; }
    public string ProducerId { get; init; }
    public ProducerDto Producer { get; init; }
}

public class BrandDto :BaseDto
{
    public string Name { get; init; }
}

public class ProducerDto :BaseDto
{
    public string Name { get; init; }
}
```

And I'm configuring my mappings without the MongoDb specific attributes.

```cs
BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap<BaseDto>(map =>
{
    map.MapIdProperty(c => c.Id)
        .SetElementName("_id")
        .SetIdGenerator(CannectIdGenerator.Instance)
        .SetSerializer(new StringSerializer(BsonType.String));

    map.MapProperty(x => x.PartitionKey).SetElementName("_partitionKey");
});

BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap<ProducerDto>(map => map.AutoMap());
BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap<BrandDto>(map => map.AutoMap());
BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap<ProductDto>(map => map.AutoMap());
```

The trouble I'm running into is that my `Product` isn't getting an auto-generated ID (the others are). Here's my transaction

```cs
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult<string>> Add(ProductDto product)
{
    using var session = await _database.Client.StartSessionAsync();
    try
    {
        session.StartTransaction();

        // NOTICE THIS IS A `BsonDocument`
        var products = _database.GetCollection<BsonDocument>(MasterCollection.Products.DisplayName);
        var brands = _database.GetCollection<BrandDto>(MasterCollection.Brands.DisplayName);
        var producers = _database.GetCollection<ProducerDto>(MasterCollection.Producers.DisplayName);

        // THIS INSERT GETS A PROPER ID
        await producers.InsertOneAsync(session, product.Producer);

        // THIS INSERT GETS A PROPER ID
        await brands.InsertOneAsync(session, product.Brand);

        var insert = product.ToBsonDocument();
        insert[nameof(ProductDto.Brand)] = insert[nameof(ProductDto.BrandId)] = product.Brand.Id;
        insert[nameof(ProductDto.Producer)] = insert[nameof(ProductDto.ProducerId)] = product.Producer.Id;


        // THIS INSERT DOES NOT GET AN ID, INSTEAD IT JUST STAYS `null`
        await products.InsertOneAsync(session, insert);

        await session.CommitTransactionAsync();
        return Ok(insert["_id"]);
    }
    catch
    {
        await session.AbortTransactionAsync();
        return Problem("Transaction Aborted");
    }
}
```

What I'm trying to avoid is to have to manually initialize the ID field, I'd much prefer it to happen as a part of an insert.

Comment: you should check your repro. Simplified case of your code (without unrelated details about Dto configuration) works to me and `_id` value is configured in the resulted `insert` BsonDocument

Comment: this behavior happens because calling `.ToBsonDocument()` already generates `_id` field with `null` value. This forces driver to skip autogenerating `_id`. You should remove this element before call `Insert`

Comment: ooh that's interesting. I'll give it a try, thanks.